# Ubuntu Gnome 20.04 + VirtualBox + NVidia Driver 450.57 don't want to coexist

Tags: drivers, nvidia, virtualbox

Intel 8700K
NVidia GTX 970
Ubuntu 20.04.1
Kernel 5.4.0-45
Gnome 3.36.3

I'm having issues with my VMs (virtualbox) since the 20.04 update.

Ever since the update, VirtualBox VMs stopped working. I'm getting an error message:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

When I do install virtualbox-dkms, the NVidia driver stops working and needs reinstallation. When I reinstall the NVidia driver, virtualbox stops working... endless loop.

I'm not sure which display server is running anymore on this system.

```
ps -e | grep tty
   1536 tty1     00:00:00 gdm-x-session
   1538 tty1     00:00:02 Xorg
   1785 tty1     00:00:00 gnome-session-b
   2730 tty2     00:00:00 gdm-x-session
   2732 tty2     00:05:01 Xorg
   2740 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-session-b
```

I guess Xorg.

This computer is running Ubuntu since 2010 (10.04) and was updated to latest versions with every iteration LTS and non-LTS since then. Never reformatted even when I swapped the entire motherboard-cpu-gpu when I changed hardware. Just dropped the SSD into the new hardware and it just booted up. Twice... While also planning right now for a third transplantation of the SSD to the latest mobo-cpu-gpu system (intel/nvidia)

Anyone facing similar problems? Anyone have a solution? How can I install the latest NVidia driver and virtualbox-dkms and have them work without one crashing the other everytiem??

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Got the same error when using virtualbox 5.2.44 on Linux mint with kernel 5.8.5. When I changed to the signed kernel 5.4.x, I was able to install virtualbox and boot the vbox image perfectly. I am also using Nvidia driver 450.66 which works only on the unsigned mainline kernel. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet. No solution for me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a discussion related to this bug in Virtualbox forums, which is now fixed. (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=99611)

Latest version of Virtualbox 6.1.14 for Eoan worked for me (https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.14/)

Comment: @Nmath This might benefit from expansion but it's not a link-only answer. Even if it only said to use VirtualBox 6.1.14, it would be an answer. *Also* having links doesn't make it not one. If the links broke, it would still be fully understandable as saying the problem went away in newer versions of VirtualBox and the fix is to use version 6.1.14 (or presumably any later one). As [Shog9 put it](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15889), "A link-only answer is an answer that consists of *zero* relevant information beyond a link that *may* point at useful information elsewhere." (emphasis in original)